# My question got down-voted and I want to know how I can re-open it

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, reopen-closed

Here is the question : [Is ASCII code 7-bit or 8-bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14690159/605618)

It asks whether ASCII is 7-bit or 8-bit. Yes, it details how a teacher got me thinking about it but it is not a homework question. And as the answer rightly details, it told me how ASCII as interpreted today is really as a subset of UNICODE. So, in the face of conflicting definitions, I should really lean towards the 8-bit encoding i.e. with the higher bit set low.

This is what I glean from the answer and the fact that I have had multiple up-votes in the past means that it really is a valid query of people after all. I don't want to sound like a whiner, yet I don't understand the reason it can be constituted as "not a real question".

In short: how can it be interpreted as such? And what are the ways to edit the question so that it becomes acceptable to SO standards given that I find myself unable to reword the question - I just don't know what more to add! (There is hardly anything in there to take away.)

Help, pretty please!

Comment: Just curious—why are you asking this almost a year after it's been closed?

Comment: I have no comment on your question as a whole, but I would say that upvotes do not have a direct correlation with quality, just with popularity.

Comment: @slhck I got curious too. Since I have already got answer, this question is mostly a theoretical one for me now to know how SO works.

Answer (score 5):

The issue isn't that it got downvoted; it's that people voted to close it.  Why?  Well, it isn't really an on-topic question for SO, because it's not about a particular programming problem. It asks for an opinion ("can't it be argued," "what do we mean," etc.). It's really a question about the definition of ASCII, which is an interesting comp sci question (hence the upvotes), but not a programming question (hence the downvotes and close votes).

Comment: This question fits the [Computer Science](http://cs.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: @leesei Are you sure? As far as I can see you do not any participation on CS. Regardless, the question is older than 60 days and therefore cannot be migrated. Also, questions aren't migrated to Beta sites.

Comment: But it is a programming question. It tells us what should be considered valid ASCII and what not, so that I can properly decode any ASCII stream. Right now, I am trying to convert UTF8 to UTF32 so I do understand the need of nitpicking.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the relevance to your problem of how many bytes it *requires* to encode ASCII. You can convert UTF8 to UTF32 encodings without caring about whether ASCII is truly a 7- or 8-bit set. But the point is that your question doesn't ask, "How do I do/calculate [whatever] with respect to ASCII characters?" As written, it's a theoretical question about the nature of ASCII, which does not present a concrete programming problem.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I get it. I was just trying to gauge the boundary of my questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You are asking a question that a programmer might have, but not a question which can be solved using programming.

Thus it is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: But Stack overflow has tons of questions clarifying various aspects of programming languages; for example, SO should be considered the most exhaustive resource on C++ (apart from the standard itself, which is really not readable) due to the questions asked by various people here. And they are mostly differences or definition questions only.

Comment: ASCII isn't a programming language.  You might get away with asking about how a specific programming language handles ascii in relation to a problem you're having processing ascii, but asking about ascii itself isn't any different than asking about morse code.  Without specific application to programming, it isn't on topic.